# Mixed slurm cluster with nodes ThreadsPerCore=1 and 2

Tags: multithreading, configuration, slurm

I'm testing a SLURM cluster putting together one physical node and one Virtual Machine:

Physical node (from `slurmd -C`)

```
NodeName=tpc2 **CPUs=80** Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=20
**ThreadsPerCore=2** RealMemory=515620
```

Virtual machine (from `slurmd -C`)

```
NodeName=tpc1 **CPUs=32** Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=32
**ThreadsPerCore=1** RealMemory=190210
```

In the `slurm.conf` I have setup for scheduler options:

```
SchedulerType=sched/backfill

SelectType=select/cons_res

SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory
```

Running `sinfo` I see that both are under the same partition and in the `idle` status.

I'm testing the mini cluster with the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=TEST
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=1G
sleep 300
```

According to the configuration file what I would expect is ... if I submit jobs with `--cpus-per-task=1`, I should have 80 jobs under *tpc2* and 32 jobs under *tpc1*.

BUT, what I really see is to have 40 jobs under *tpc2* and 32 jobs under *tpc1*. Is it like assign a per core per job and not a thread?

In general, is possible to combine a node with `ThreadsPerCore=2` and one with `ThreadsPerCore=1` in the same SLURM cluster? If yes, how can I run jobs assigning threads and not cores (in the way to fully use the *tpc2*)? Any advice to fix the configuration file is welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Two answers based on two different scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

Assumption: your `slurm.conf` file has different entries than actual hardware.

If your conf file has entries of `40` and `32` for the nodes *tpc2* and *tpc1*. If you change the number of CPUs in your `slurm.conf` file to match the hardware, then you can utilise the full number of CPUS.

`slurmd -C` will display the actual hardware information instead of the information from `slurm.conf` file.

> -C
> Print the actual hardware configuration (not the configuration from the slurm.conf file) and exit. The format of output is the same
> as used in slurm.conf to describe a node's configuration plus its
> uptime.

That means, if you specify the `CPUs=40` in `slurm.conf` file and your machine has `80` CPUs, when you do `slurmd -C` you will see `80` in the output but your slurm will only allocate the `40`CPUs mentioned in the configuration file for running the jobs.

**Scenario 2:**

When using a `SelectType` of `select/cons_res` or `select/cons_tres` and `CR_CPU_Memory`, the hyperthreads might not be counted as CPUs.

To count each thread as a CPU, you could also use `CR_Core_Memory` in the slurm conf file instead of `CR_CPU_Memory`.

```
### Scheduler
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core_Memory
```

From the documentation:

> CR_Core_Memory
> Cores and memory are consumable resources. On nodes with hyper-threads, each thread is counted as a CPU to satisfy a job's
> resource requirement, but multiple jobs are not allocated threads on
> the same core. The count of CPUs allocated to a job may be rounded up
> to account for every CPU on an allocated core. Setting a value for
> DefMemPerCPU is strongly recommended.